# Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0

Tags: macos, wifi, logs

I found the following in my wifi.log file after l connected to wifi:

> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issue comparing a different message code, here is Cisco's explanation of deauth reason code 9:

> 9  Station requesting (re)association is not authenticated with responding station NOT SUPPORTED

From: [802.11 Association Status, 802.11 Deauth Reason codes](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/141136/80211-association-status-80211-deauth-reason-codes)

Not sure if that helps. Good luck.